# Microfrontend This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component

Tags: reactjs, recoiljs

Build two microfrontends using recoil frontend when accessed indepentenly works fine, when integrated into parent project it shows  error.

Central package for state management was developed to handle states across multiple frontends. That package is used on root level it still throws same error. Tried added  on multiple locations still same error of "This component must be used inside a  component" after build.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you a eventrix for state management in microfrontend applications. It has a built-in event bus so you can communicate between elements of your application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).